# Button width not set to the assigned value

Tags: wpf

I am implementing a Grid of button with 3 columns one shown and other 2 are collapsed to start with.
Have set the Grid width to be Auto
Set the shown button size to BUTTONWIDTH = 50
Set the collapsed buttons size to EXTNBUTTONWIDTH = 20

I show the Collapsed buttons only button click event of the first button. I see that neither button sizes are honored the width size I have specified. when I look at the width of the button in debugger, width and maxwidth is 50 but actualwidth is 98. However the height of the buttons are displayed as I have set.

I have attached the code, please have a look and give me your suggestion on how to fix the issue.

```
for (int leftCol = 0; leftCol < 3; leftCol++)
        {

            this.leftButtonGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            for (int leftRow = 0; leftRow < CHARTDOMLEN; leftRow++)
            {
                this.leftButtonGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

                Button btnOrderSell = new Button();
                btnOrderSell.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

                btnOrderSell.Height = BUTTONHEIGHT;
                btnOrderSell.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                // To avoid double borderline
                if (leftRow > 0)
                    btnOrderSell.BorderThickness = new Thickness() { Top = 0, Bottom = 1, Left = 1, Right = 1 };

                btnOrderSell.Click += Button_Click;
                if (leftCol == 0)
                {
                    btnOrderSell.MaxWidth = BUTTONWIDTH;
                    btnOrderSell.Width = BUTTONWIDTH;
                    this.TL0[leftRow] = btnOrderSell;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnOrderSell.MaxWidth = EXTNBUTTONWIDTH;
                    btnOrderSell.Width = EXTNBUTTONWIDTH;
                    btnOrderSell.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (leftCol == 1)
                    {
                        this.TL1[leftRow] = btnOrderSell;
                    }
                    else
                        this.TL2[leftRow] = btnOrderSell;                        
                }
                Grid.SetColumn(btnOrderSell, leftCol);
                Grid.SetRow(btnOrderSell, leftRow);
                this.leftButtonGrid.Children.Add(btnOrderSell);
            }
        }
```

XAML code

```
<Grid x:Name="OrderBuyGridButtons">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!--<Button x:Name="btn00" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed" />-->
<Button x:Name="btn00" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<!--<Button x:Name="btn01" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="30"  Visibility="Collapsed" />-->
<Button x:Name="btn01" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed" />

<!--<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="80" />-->
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="80" Background="Gainsboro" Click="Button_Click" BorderBrush="Black"/>
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Width="80" Background="Gainsboro" BorderBrush="Black"/>
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Width="80" Background="Gainsboro" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

Comment: Redo it in XAML.

Comment: Is that just to test ? as I do not want to do it in XAML for production.

Comment: Do it in XAML in production.

Comment: will moving to XAML fix the issue?, what is in XAML that cannot work with code?.

Comment: Moving to XAML will make it easy to do this kind of thing without creating bugs that you need help to find.

Comment: Ok will try as a test code to start with if it is fixed then I will see if I can use that xaml in the code. Thanks for your inputs BTW.

Comment: Ed Plunkett, Same thing done in XAML also did not work. If I keep the columndefinition width as Auto, the hidden buttons when they show up has the size of 50, which is what was happening even in that piece of code. (stackoverflow suggest not to have extended discussion and switch to chat, but I dont have access to chat either)

Comment: Can you show me the XAML?

Comment: was too long, so sent it as answer

Comment: I tried your XAML and the ActualWidth of all of the buttons is exactly the same as the Width. If `Width="80"`, then `ActualWidth` is 80.

Comment: I am placing these buttons on a chart control, if it is directly on a form then it is working fine I think. so does that mean it is some thing to do with chart control.

Comment: Must be. I can't find a way to break the XAML you gave me, though. Did you try setting the width of the third column to 80 instead of *?